# JS: convert Array to readable JSON-Array with key-pairs for each value

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

i want to convert my Array:

```
var calGroups = ["201701", "201702", "201703", "201704", ""];
```

into a JSON that looks like this:

```
{ calGroups: [ {"calGroup": "201701"}, {"calGroup": "201702"}, {"calGroup": "201703"}, {"calGroup": "201704"}, {"calGroup": ""}]}
```

please help me out, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try out that:

```js
var calGroups = ["201701", "201702", "201703", "201704", ""];
var json = JSON.stringify({calGroups:calGroups.map(calGroup => ({calGroup}))});
console.log(json);
```

The variable `json` will be a string with the following content:

```
{"calGroups":[{"calGroup":"201701"},{"calGroup":"201702"},{"calGroup":"201703"},{"calGroup":"201704"},{"calGroup":""}]}
```

Comment: thx, this helped a lot! Do you have any idea why my question got such a negative voting? :/